# What are the names of the study of words and of the study of sentences in English?

Tags: terminology, sentences

What is the name of the study of words in English?

How do you call the study of sentences in English?

Does English grammar or linguistics concerns about the study of units larger than sentences?

What other units do English grammar or linguistics study, according to this order "... < word < sentence < paragraph < ..."?

Thanks.

Comment: This stuff is all very basic. You should at least have read [the Wikipedia article on Linguistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistics) before asking questions here.

Comment: 1. Lexicology, aka lexical semantics, and morphology. 2. Syntax. 3. Yes. 4. Text.

Answer (score 3):

**Morphology**: the study of the structure of words

**Etymology**: the study of the history of words

**Syntax**: the study of the structure of sentences

**Discourse analysis**: the study of conversations and texts